# How to use window.open in lightning components?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, component

As a [security best practice](https://mathiasbynens.github.io/rel-noopener/), usually when we open new windows with Javascript, we remove the `opener` property so that the page we open can't call `window.opener` and get full control of our Salesforce instance.

The common way to do this (from the article) in code is:

```
const otherWindow = window.open();
otherWindow.opener = null;
otherWindow.location = url;
```

However, in Salesforce components, the window object appears to be destroyed and not the browser window. So the first call to `window.open()` immediately opens a window to a location like:

```
https://...force.com/lightning/r/.../undefined
```

How do we prevent security flaws with the destroyed Aura component `window` object?

Comment: It's not destroyed, it's wrapped (via SecureWindow). However, I'm pretty sure it's not supposed to behave this way. I'd say that a bug probably needs to be logged.

Answer (score 1):

After tracing through the source, it looks like using an undefined first parameter is what causes this behavior. You can fix the first part by explicitly providing an empty url:

```
const otherWindow = window.open('');
```

However, once you do this, otherWindow is now a SecureWindow, so you won't get access to otherWindow.location (it will return as undefined). In other words, this path is a non-starter.

You could probably use the lightning:navigation component to specify a location, but this won't work outside of basic Lightning experiences (Lightning, Communities, Mobile App), so not available in Lightning Out or Lightning Apps, etc.

I'd recommend logging a bug, as I'm pretty sure it is one. It should also be reasonable for SecureWindow to provide access to the remote site's location attribute (perhaps filtered to be write-only?). For now, you will probably want to just open a page you know you control (e.g. a Visualforce page) and use that to springboard to the final destination securely.

Comment: I certainly appreciate the irony that it's called "SecureWindow"

Comment: @AndyRay It is still more secure than the default window object, it just has what appears to be a flaw. For example, two components in different namespaces can't use window to communicate, because it's no longer truly global.